# Рекурсивно разобрать массив объектов на JS

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! Никак не получается рекурсивно разобрать массив

```js
{//Подается на вход
    "Name": "Level_1",
    "GUID": "fac21c7a-69e8",
    "Property": {
        "P": [{
            "Name": "Level_2_1",
            "GUID": "fac21c98-69e8",
            "Property": {
                "P": [{
                    "Name": "Level_3_1",
                    "GUID": "fac21ca6-69e8",
                    "Property": {},
                    "Dir": false
                }, {
                    "Name": "Level_3_2",
                    "GUID": "fac21c9f-69e8",
                    "Property": {},
                    "Dir": false
                }, {
                    "Name": "Level_3_3",
                    "GUID": "fac21ca2-69e8",
                    "Property": {},
                    "Dir": false
                }]
            },
            "Dir": true
        }, {
            "Name": "Level_2_2",
            "GUID": "fac21c81-69e8",
            "Property": {
                "P": [{
                    "Name": "Level_3_4",
                    "GUID": "fac21c82-69e8",
                    "Property": {},
                    "Dir": false
                }, {
                    "Name": "Level_3_5",
                    "GUID": "fac21c83-69e8",
                    "Property": {},
                    "Dir": false
                }]
            },
            "Dir": true
        }, {
            "Name": "Level_2_3",
            "GUID": "fac21cb0-69e8",
            "Property": {
                "P": {
                    "Name": "Level_3_6",
                    "GUID": "fac21cb1-69e8",
                    "Property": {},
                    "Dir": false
                }
            },
            "Dir": true
        }, {
            "Name": "Level_2_4",
            "GUID": "f71c31f0-9aab",
            "Property": {
                "P": {
                    "Name": "Level_3_7",
                    "GUID": "188b9a27-9aac",
                    "Property": {},
                    "Dir": false
                }
            },
            "Dir": true
        }]
    },
    "Dir": true
}


function select(mass) {
    var div = $("#divN");
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    if (typeof mass == 'object') {
        newmass.push(mass)
    }
    factorial(newmass)
    function factorial(mass) {
        mass.forEach(function (v) {
            if (v.dir == false) {
                return false;
            } else {
                var fguid = v.GUID.split("-")[0];//
                fguid = fguid.replace(/[^-0-9]/gim, '');
                div.append('<div id="folder' + fguid + '" class="folder" onclick="toggle(' + fguid + ')">' + v.Name + '</div>');

                if (v.Property.P.length > 0) {
                    if (typeof v.Property.P == 'object') {
                        for (var key in v.Property.P) {
                            console.log('factorial ' + v.Property.P[key].Name)
                            if (typeof v.Property.P == 'object' && v.Property.P.dir == false) {
                                var m = []
                                m.push(v.Property.P)
                                factorial(m);
                                div.append('<div id="str' + fguid + '" class="str  str' + fguid + '" onclick="emptyService(this.innerHTML)">' + v.Property.P[key].Name + '</div>');
                            } else {
                                factorial(v.Property.P);
                                div.append('<div id="str' + fguid + '" class="str  str' + fguid + '" onclick="emptyService(this.innerHTML)">' + v.Property.P[key].Name + '</div>');
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        v.Property.P.forEach(function (k) {
                            factorial(k.Property.P);
                            div.append('<div id="str' + fguid + '" class="str  str' + fguid + '" onclick="emptyService(this.innerHTML)">' + k.Property.P.Name + '</div>');
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Сниппеты для кода, который можно запустить

Comment: а что вообще должен делать этот код?

Comment: должен получиться иерархический список Name состоящий из divов

Comment: До "Name": "Level_2_3" он разбирает нормально, а дальше происходит путаница и много повторений

Comment: почему функция называется factorial. и что за newmass, который нигде не объявлен?

Comment: Просто так называется) 
Видимо случайно удалил вместе с комментом. Объявляется так _var newmass = [];_ перед _newmass.push(mass)_